# I can't send mails from Outlook

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, vps

I have a domain, and a VPS, and I install CPanel.

When I send a mail, this can't receive for the other one that I send the mail.

I check DNS and rDNS but I can't find any error.

Someone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your domain MX record and correct it.

Also check your mail services status. May be it's not working correctly on your server.